# random effects and clustered errors

Tags: panel-data, random-effects-model, model, clustered-standard-errors

I am running a panel model using an linear regressor. A Haussman test indicates that the random effects model is better than a fixed effects. I am also clustering the errors on country code.

I would just like some sober second thought on this approach. In my view, random effects and clustering do slightly different things. RE is more about the coefficient and clustering is more about the significance (standard errors), to put it crudely. If so, running a model with both would actually be a fairly good idea, especially since RE models have such strong assumptions.

Happy to be proven wrong (or right, of course).

Any impressions would be welcome.

Comment: If the random effects model is capturing the heterogeneity in the data, why do you need to do further "corrections" to the standard errors?

Comment: If the 'strong assumptions' are that first level covariates $X$ are uncorrelated with random effect, then no random effects modeler has *had* to assume this since Mundlak 1978. They can always just center $X$ by group and add group averages $\bar{X}$ as predictors at level 2. See e.g. http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=9452105&fileId=S2049847014000077

Answer (score 1):

In the usual setting (in most programs) the hausman test in valid only under full set of random effects assumptions. In this case it makes no sense to report robust standard errors because, even while they are still valid, they will less efficient per definition (you have a loss with no gain).

Other than this; yes you are correct it always makes sense to report robust standard errors (and most people do) since the assumption needed for the usual standard errors to be correct are strict and (somewhat) arbitrary.